# Duplicated links between networks switches, are they bad ? Do in a VLAN would they both be tagged?

Tags: networking, vlan

Ive got a LAN i need to setup a couple of VLANs on.

The network typology is as per the following screenshot.

It would seem that link `d` is not required. But the cable management on this project is not the best an im scared to unplug it incase its serving a purpose i dont know about. Is there anything bad about leaving this cable in place.

When configuring my VLAN would it work if i made both `c` and `d` (as well as `a` and `b`) trunk links ?

[image: network topology screenshot]

Comment: It depends on the configuration. Depending on IP ranges and configuration it should be possible to have the GS108 **only** talk to the 716 via link d. Which would be sensible if the links between the switches are bottlenecks.  Also, dpending on the setup it might change routes when one of the connections drops (e.g. communicate from 108 via 105 (b) to 716 (c), until link is lost and then switch to (d). So it could have a purpose, but without config info noone here can state if that is the case of not.

Comment: @Hennes, thanks, im confident in saying there has been no config set on these switches other than plugging them in and making sure they communicate with one another, and changing the passwords.

Comment: In that case the defaults on the switches have sensible settings, because with dumb switches the first broadcast packet would have been interesting. (See broadcast storm). So none manually set, but unknown default setting still applied.

Comment: Do the switches have STP or RSTP enabled?

Comment: @grawity the GS716t has STP enabled by default,  the other 2 switches dont seem to have STP as far as i can tell, all though they do having something called loop detection which is disabled on both of them